# Displaying products by category in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Rails beginner here.  I want to display a list of all products belonging to a specific category.  I wanted to keep it simple, so each product has only one category. When I show the category, the products are there, but they appear in an array, like this:

> > Name: Soldering
> >
> > Category ID: 2
> >
> > Products: [#< Product id: 5, title: "Hacksaw", description: "Finetooth Hacksaw", image_url: >>"hacksaw.jpg", price: #, created_at: "2012-07-14 >>22:34:07", updated_at: "2012-07-17 22:18:14", category_id: 2, category_name: nil>, #< Product id:8, >>title: "Torch", description: "Welding Torch", image_url: "torch.jpg", price: >>#, created_at: "2012-07-15 08:40:05", >>updated_at: "2012-07-15 08:40:05", category_id: 2, category_name: nil>]

This is the categories/show.html.erb:

```
<p>
  <b>Products:</b>
  <%= @category.products %></p>
</p>
```

And the categories controller:

```
def show
  @category = Category.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @category }
  end
end
```

What I want to do is just display a list of the products names, but when I try this in the show.html.erb:

```
<p>
    <b>Products:</b>
    <%= @category.product.name %></p>
</p>
```

...I get the following error:

> > undefined method `product' for #< Category:0x007ff03cd59e98>

I can't figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to iterate through your `@category.products`. `@category.products` will give you all the `Product` models that belong to `@category`.

`@category` (the `Category`, which *has a collection of `Product`s*) will not respond to `product` - it doesn't know what that is. All it knows is it has a bunch of `Product`s.

```
<% @category.products.each do |product| %>
    <p>
        <b>Product:</b>
        <%= product.name %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Cheers Edd, it's very simple when it's explained well.

Answer (score 0):

This is something similar I have been working on.  It might help comparing.

show.html.erb

```
     <p>
      <b>Title:</b>
      <%= @product.title %>
    </p>

    <p>
      <b>Description:</b>
      <%= @product.description %>
    </p>

    <p>
      <b>Image url:</b>
      <%= @product.image_url %>
    </p>

    <p>
      <b>Price:</b>
      <%= @product.price %>
    </p>
```

controller

```
  def show
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @product }
    end
  end
```